# Safely round to next smaller multiple

Tags: c++

Consider:

```
int a, b;
int c = b * (a / b)
```

I think it should be pretty clear what it does *for positive numbers*: c is set to the multiple of b which is next smaller relative to a.

Example: Let `b = 2`, then:

```
a = 0 => c = 0
a = 1 => c = 0
a = 2 => c = 2
a = 3 => c = 2
```

For negative numbers, however, it works the opposite way: It takes the next bigger (less negative) multiple of b. **What is the best approach to also pick the next smaller (more negative) multiple of b?**

Comment: Could you give an example for the negative case? State what happens, and what should happen. Cheers,

Comment: @Bathsheba : `a : 0 b : -2 c :0
a : -1 b : -2 c :0
a : -2 b : -2 c :-2
a : -3 b : -2 c :-2` This is the result for negative numbers

Comment: `if(c < 0) c += b;`?

Comment: @CompuChip : But that may not always be a multiple of b

Comment: @Bathsheba : I guess the expected behaviour is `a : 0 b : -2 c :0
a : -1 b : -2 c :-2
a : -2 b : -2 c :-2
a : -3 b : -2 c :-4`

Comment: Answers based on guesswork ought to be downvoted to oblivion. I'm outahere!

Comment: @Bathsheba I don't see how my answer is based on guess work.

Comment: @Bathsheba see edited comment.

Comment: Just updated my answer. It should work consistently regardless of the signs of the two numbers involved.

Comment: Interesting to see that the OP ran away without explaining further.. OP are you out there? Good though, universal solutions have emerged !!

Comment: No worries, OP just had lunch ;-) I think the answer by Linxi shows that the question is clear and has a clear answer. Or what should I add to get even better anwers?

Comment: I just wanted an example of the negative case as per my very first comment. There could be a more compact way of doing this than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int round_down(int val, int unit) {
  std::div_t div_result = std::div(val, unit);
  int candidate = div_result.quot * unit;
  return candidate <= val ? candidate : 
         unit >= 0 ? candidate - unit :
         candidate + unit;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << round_down(9, 7) << std::endl;
  std::cout << round_down(13, 2) << std::endl;
  std::cout << round_down(15, 3) << std::endl;

  std::cout << round_down(-9, 7) << std::endl;
  std::cout << round_down(-13, 2) << std::endl;
  std::cout << round_down(-15, 3) << std::endl;

  std::cout << round_down(9, -7) << std::endl;
  std::cout << round_down(13, -2) << std::endl;
  std::cout << round_down(15, -3) << std::endl;

  std::cout << round_down(-9, -7) << std::endl;
  std::cout << round_down(-13, -2) << std::endl;
  std::cout << round_down(-15, -3) << std::endl;
}
```

Note that, until C++11, the rounding direction of the built-in division operator `/` is implementation-defined. So, I'm using `std::div()` instead. Quoted from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Multiplicative_operators) (emphasis mine):

> The binary operator / divides the first operand by the second (after
>   usual arithmetic conversions).
>   For integral operands, it yields the
>   algebraic quotient.
>   **The quotient is rounded in implementation-defined direction. (until C++11)**
>   The quotient is
>   truncated towards zero (fractional part is discarded). (since C++11)
>   ...
>   Note: Until C++11, if one or both operands to binary operator %
>   were negative, the sign of the remainder was implementation-defined,
>   as it depends on the rounding direction of integer division. **The
>   function std::div provided well-defined behavior in that case.**

Comment: Nice that you have put the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to subtract `b+1` from your `a` if `a<0` before you pas it to your function:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "---------------------------------" << endl;
    for (int bi = 1; bi < 10; bi++)
    {
        for (int ai = -10; ai < 10; ai++)
        {
            int a = ai;
            int b = bi;

            if (a < 0)
                a -= b + 1;

            int c = b * (std::div(a / b));
            cout << "a = " << a << ",b = " << b << " => c = " << c << endl;
        }
        cout << "---------------------------------" << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------
a = -12,b = 1 => c = -12
a = -11,b = 1 => c = -11
a = -10,b = 1 => c = -10
a = -9,b = 1 => c = -9
a = -8,b = 1 => c = -8
a = -7,b = 1 => c = -7
a = -6,b = 1 => c = -6
a = -5,b = 1 => c = -5
a = -4,b = 1 => c = -4
a = -3,b = 1 => c = -3
a = 0,b = 1 => c = 0
a = 1,b = 1 => c = 1
a = 2,b = 1 => c = 2
a = 3,b = 1 => c = 3
a = 4,b = 1 => c = 4
a = 5,b = 1 => c = 5
a = 6,b = 1 => c = 6
a = 7,b = 1 => c = 7
a = 8,b = 1 => c = 8
a = 9,b = 1 => c = 9
---------------------------------
a = -13,b = 2 => c = -12
a = -12,b = 2 => c = -12
a = -11,b = 2 => c = -10
a = -10,b = 2 => c = -10
a = -9,b = 2 => c = -8
a = -8,b = 2 => c = -8
a = -7,b = 2 => c = -6
a = -6,b = 2 => c = -6
a = -5,b = 2 => c = -4
a = -4,b = 2 => c = -4
a = 0,b = 2 => c = 0
a = 1,b = 2 => c = 0
a = 2,b = 2 => c = 2
a = 3,b = 2 => c = 2
a = 4,b = 2 => c = 4
a = 5,b = 2 => c = 4
a = 6,b = 2 => c = 6
a = 7,b = 2 => c = 6
a = 8,b = 2 => c = 8
a = 9,b = 2 => c = 8
---------------------------------
a = -14,b = 3 => c = -12
a = -13,b = 3 => c = -12
a = -12,b = 3 => c = -12
a = -11,b = 3 => c = -9
a = -10,b = 3 => c = -9
a = -9,b = 3 => c = -9
a = -8,b = 3 => c = -6
a = -7,b = 3 => c = -6
a = -6,b = 3 => c = -6
a = -5,b = 3 => c = -3
a = 0,b = 3 => c = 0
a = 1,b = 3 => c = 0
a = 2,b = 3 => c = 0
a = 3,b = 3 => c = 3
a = 4,b = 3 => c = 3
a = 5,b = 3 => c = 3
a = 6,b = 3 => c = 6
a = 7,b = 3 => c = 6
a = 8,b = 3 => c = 6
a = 9,b = 3 => c = 9
---------------------------------
a = -15,b = 4 => c = -12
a = -14,b = 4 => c = -12
a = -13,b = 4 => c = -12
a = -12,b = 4 => c = -12
a = -11,b = 4 => c = -8
a = -10,b = 4 => c = -8
a = -9,b = 4 => c = -8
a = -8,b = 4 => c = -8
a = -7,b = 4 => c = -4
a = -6,b = 4 => c = -4
a = 0,b = 4 => c = 0
a = 1,b = 4 => c = 0
a = 2,b = 4 => c = 0
a = 3,b = 4 => c = 0
a = 4,b = 4 => c = 4
a = 5,b = 4 => c = 4
a = 6,b = 4 => c = 4
a = 7,b = 4 => c = 4
a = 8,b = 4 => c = 8
a = 9,b = 4 => c = 8
---------------------------------
a = -16,b = 5 => c = -15
a = -15,b = 5 => c = -15
a = -14,b = 5 => c = -10
a = -13,b = 5 => c = -10
a = -12,b = 5 => c = -10
a = -11,b = 5 => c = -10
a = -10,b = 5 => c = -10
a = -9,b = 5 => c = -5
a = -8,b = 5 => c = -5
a = -7,b = 5 => c = -5
a = 0,b = 5 => c = 0
a = 1,b = 5 => c = 0
a = 2,b = 5 => c = 0
a = 3,b = 5 => c = 0
a = 4,b = 5 => c = 0
a = 5,b = 5 => c = 5
a = 6,b = 5 => c = 5
a = 7,b = 5 => c = 5
a = 8,b = 5 => c = 5
a = 9,b = 5 => c = 5
---------------------------------
a = -17,b = 6 => c = -12
a = -16,b = 6 => c = -12
a = -15,b = 6 => c = -12
a = -14,b = 6 => c = -12
a = -13,b = 6 => c = -12
a = -12,b = 6 => c = -12
a = -11,b = 6 => c = -6
a = -10,b = 6 => c = -6
a = -9,b = 6 => c = -6
a = -8,b = 6 => c = -6
a = 0,b = 6 => c = 0
a = 1,b = 6 => c = 0
a = 2,b = 6 => c = 0
a = 3,b = 6 => c = 0
a = 4,b = 6 => c = 0
a = 5,b = 6 => c = 0
a = 6,b = 6 => c = 6
a = 7,b = 6 => c = 6
a = 8,b = 6 => c = 6
a = 9,b = 6 => c = 6
---------------------------------
a = -18,b = 7 => c = -14
a = -17,b = 7 => c = -14
a = -16,b = 7 => c = -14
a = -15,b = 7 => c = -14
a = -14,b = 7 => c = -14
a = -13,b = 7 => c = -7
a = -12,b = 7 => c = -7
a = -11,b = 7 => c = -7
a = -10,b = 7 => c = -7
a = -9,b = 7 => c = -7
a = 0,b = 7 => c = 0
a = 1,b = 7 => c = 0
a = 2,b = 7 => c = 0
a = 3,b = 7 => c = 0
a = 4,b = 7 => c = 0
a = 5,b = 7 => c = 0
a = 6,b = 7 => c = 0
a = 7,b = 7 => c = 7
a = 8,b = 7 => c = 7
a = 9,b = 7 => c = 7
---------------------------------
a = -19,b = 8 => c = -16
a = -18,b = 8 => c = -16
a = -17,b = 8 => c = -16
a = -16,b = 8 => c = -16
a = -15,b = 8 => c = -8
a = -14,b = 8 => c = -8
a = -13,b = 8 => c = -8
a = -12,b = 8 => c = -8
a = -11,b = 8 => c = -8
a = -10,b = 8 => c = -8
a = 0,b = 8 => c = 0
a = 1,b = 8 => c = 0
a = 2,b = 8 => c = 0
a = 3,b = 8 => c = 0
a = 4,b = 8 => c = 0
a = 5,b = 8 => c = 0
a = 6,b = 8 => c = 0
a = 7,b = 8 => c = 0
a = 8,b = 8 => c = 8
a = 9,b = 8 => c = 8
---------------------------------
a = -20,b = 9 => c = -18
a = -19,b = 9 => c = -18
a = -18,b = 9 => c = -18
a = -17,b = 9 => c = -9
a = -16,b = 9 => c = -9
a = -15,b = 9 => c = -9
a = -14,b = 9 => c = -9
a = -13,b = 9 => c = -9
a = -12,b = 9 => c = -9
a = -11,b = 9 => c = -9
a = 0,b = 9 => c = 0
a = 1,b = 9 => c = 0
a = 2,b = 9 => c = 0
a = 3,b = 9 => c = 0
a = 4,b = 9 => c = 0
a = 5,b = 9 => c = 0
a = 6,b = 9 => c = 0
a = 7,b = 9 => c = 0
a = 8,b = 9 => c = 0
a = 9,b = 9 => c = 9
---------------------------------
```

Comment: According to the answer by Lingxi, this won't work savely due to the non-defined rounding behavior of the `/`before C++11.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of the code that you quote is actually correct. The definition of division for negative integers is such that, for **m**, and **n** being positive integers, the following is true:

-(m)/n = -(m/n)

Therefore I am assuming here that what you are actually asking is how to get:

```
a = -1 => c = -2
a = -2 => c = -2
a = -3 => c = -4
a = -4 => c = -4
a = -5 => c = -6
```

In that case, do not use integer division, it's not what you want. What you want is the floor of the floating point division. Luckily, there's the floor function that will do it for you. Try this:

```
int c = b * floor((double)a / (double)b);
```

and it should give you exactly what you want.

Comment: Isn't that an extremely costly solution? Convert to floating point, floating point division, find next smaller integer. Meanwhile, in integers, you can do it with one integer comparison, one integer addition, and finally an integer division.

Comment: Furthermore: Will this work for numbers with extremely large absolute values?

Comment: Michael:
1. Yes, you can. And there are other ways too. I was merely trying to illustrate that what the OP actually wanted was not (always) the result of the plain old integer division.
2. Define "extremely large"?