# assert(3 / 2 == 1): Does this work?

Tags: c++, optimization, assert

I just learned that the rounding behavior of the division operator was not defined before C++ 11. The solution is to use `std::div`. ([Safely round to next smaller multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956318/savely-round-to-next-smaller-multiple/33957317#33957317))

My programs always assumed that `/` would just truncate the fractional part. As a quick fix, I'd like to include an assertion so that I get at least an error if someone would compile on a platform which has a different rounding behavior.

Will `assert(3 / 2 == 1)` or `static_assert(3 / 2 == 1)` do the job? Or will those constants be optimized away by a compiler-internal arithmetic which might be different from what the machine actually does?

Comment: [`assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) doesn't give you compiler errors, for that you need [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert).

Comment: Sorry for that. It's fixed now. I do not really care whether compiler or runtime error, I'd just like to get warned if it happens... (As a quick fix.)

Answer (score 9):

"I just learned that the rounding behavior of the division operator was not defined before C++ 11". That's not true if both arguments are positive integers.

`3 / 2 == 1` is a compile time constant expression with value `true`, so that code will compile as `assert(true)`.

Consider using `static_assert` for a compile-time assertion.

Comment: The reference says: "The quotient is rounded in implementation-defined direction." I do not see a restriction on negative values. (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Multiplicative_operators)

Comment: @Michael *"Until C++11, if one or both operands to binary operator % were negative, the sign of the remainder was implementation-defined, as it depends on the rounding direction of integer division."*

Comment: As I see it this could lead to `-3/2` being resolved to `1`, `2`, `-1` or `-2`

Comment: @Michael, 1) In both C++03 and C++11: `(a/b)*b + a%b` is equal to `a`. 2) `a % b` is non-negative if both operands are positive.